# What the difference between chrome and chrome_proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In Chromium (in Windows 10) I created a shortcut with
Menu > More tools > Create Shortcut...

So I got a shortcut launching `chrome_proxy.exe` with parameters. What is the difference between `chrome_proxy.exe` and `chrome.exe`? They seem to do the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome_proxy.exe` is a workaround so Windows does not try to follow the shortcut and load other files in the directory for icons. By doing this Windows is forced to show the icon set in the shortcut file.

It's a *binary proxy*, so any calls to `chrome_proxy.exe` just executes `chrome.exe`

You can read more about it [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/chrome/chrome_proxy/chrome_proxy_main_win.cc#23) (Chromium Code).